# Analysis and Stability Non Linear System

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, lyapunov-functions

I have this system and i want study stability:
$$ \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x_1 = x_3 \\
\dot x_2=x_4\\
\dot x_3 =\frac{1}{I}[u-bx_3-k(x_1-x_2)]\\
\dot x_4 =\frac{1}{mL^2}[k(x_1-x_2)-mgL\sin(x_2)]
\end{array}
\right. $$

I can't use phase portrait or Poincaré map because this have 4-dimension. I try to find Lyapunov candidate but for now nothing. Can help me?

Comment: Yes i can, but after? How can I proceed ?Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Assume parameters are set to 1 and if u = 0 :

1. **Case 1: (x_1 > 0), (x_2 > 0), (x_3 > 0), (x_4 > 0):**

$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{V} &= x_1x_3 + x_2x_4 - x_3^2 - x_3(x_1-x_2) + x_1x_4 - x_2x_4 - gL\sin(x_2)x_4 \\
&= \text{Positive} - \text{Negative} + \text{Positive} - \text{Negative} - \text{Negative} \\
&\text{if} < 0
\end{align*}
$$

This indicates asymptotic stability if $x_1 > x_2$ and $x_1$ is sufficiently larger than $x_2$. However, if $x_1 > x_2$ are close or if $x_1 < x_2$, further analysis may be needed.

2. **Case 2: (x_1 < 0), (x_2 < 0), (x_3 > 0), (x_4 > 0):**

$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{V} &= x_1x_3 + x_2x_4 - x_3^2 - x_3(x_1-x_2) + x_1x_4 - x_2x_4 - gL\sin(x_2)x_4 \\
&= \text{Positive} - \text{Negative} + \text{Positive} - \text{Negative} - \text{Negative} \\
&< 0
\end{align*}
$$

Similar to Case 1, if x_1 < x_2 and |x_1| is sufficiently larger than $|x_2|$, then $\dot{V} < 0$, indicating asymptotic stability.

3. **Case 3: (x_1 > 0), (x_2 < 0), (x_3 > 0), (x_4 > 0):**

$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{V} &= x_1x_3 + x_2x_4 - x_3^2 - x_3(x_1-x_2) + x_1x_4 - x_2x_4 - gL\sin(x_2)x_4 \\
&= \text{Positive} - \text{Negative} + \text{Positive} - \text{Negative} - \text{Negative} \\
&< 0
\end{align*}
$$

Similar to Case 1, if $x_1$ > $x_2$ and $x_1$ is sufficiently larger than $x_2$, then $\dot{V} < 0$, indicating asymptotic stability.

1. **Other Cases:** Cases with $x_1 < 0$ and $x_2 > 0$ or other combinations would involve similar considerations, but the stability conclusions would depend on the relative magnitudes of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and the specific values of $x_3$ and $x_4$.

To design a controller u to stabilize the system in Case 1 and Case 3, where $x_1 > 0$,$x_2 > 0$, $x_3 > 0$, and $x_4 > 0$, we can use control theory techniques. The goal is to choose a control input u such that the system's equilibrium at $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (0, 0, 0, 0)$ becomes asymptotically stable.

Since Case 2 is stable, then
Let's consider Case 1 and Case 3 separately:

**Case 1: (x_1 > 0), (x_2 > 0), (x_3 > 0), (x_4 > 0):**

The system is already asymptotically stable under the given conditions, as discussed in a previous response. Therefore, you may not need to design a controller because the system is naturally stable.

**Case 3: (x_1 > 0), (x_2 < 0), (x_3 > 0), (x_4 > 0):**

To design a controller for this case, we can use a simple proportional controller (P-controller) to stabilize the system. The control input u should be designed to drive the system towards the equilibrium point at $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (0, 0, 0, 0)$.

Let's define a control law for the P-controller:

$u = -k_1x_1 - k_2x_2$

where k_1 and k_2 are positive control gains that you can adjust to achieve the desired rate of convergence to the equilibrium. The negative sign in front of the control gains ensures that the control input tries to bring the system towards the equilibrium point.

Now, with this control input, let's examine the stability of the controlled system. Substitute the control input into the system dynamics:

$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_3 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= x_4 \\
\dot{x}_3 &= \frac{1}{I}\left[-k_1x_1 - k_2x_2 - bx_3 - k(x_1-x_2)\right] \\
\dot{x}_4 &= \frac{1}{mL^2}\left[k(x_1-x_2) - mgL\sin(x_2)\right]
\end{align*}
$$

Now, analyze the stability of this controlled system using Lyapunov's direct method with the Lyapunov function candidate $V(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ as:

$$
V(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 + x_2^2) + \frac{1}{2}(I x_3^2 + mL^2 x_4^2)
$$

Calculate $\dot{V}$ and analyze its stability properties as you did in the previous discussion. Adjust the control gains $k_1$ and $k_2$ to ensure that $\dot{V}$ is negative definite, indicating asymptotic stability.

Note that the specific values of $k_1$ and $k_2$ will depend on the desired closed-loop behavior and system characteristics, so you may need to tune these gains through simulation or experimentation to achieve the desired stability and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since $u$ is not given and for simplicity's sake, we assume that $u = 0$, $I = 1$, $m = 1$, $L = 1$, $b > 0$, $k > 0$, $g > 0$, and $0 < |x_{2}| < \pi$, then with the following Lyapunov function candidate

$$
V\left(\mathbf{x}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} & x_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} & p_{14} \\
p_{12} & p_{22} & p_{23} & p_{24} \\
p_{13} & p_{23} & p_{33} & p_{34} \\
p_{14} & p_{24} & p_{34} & p_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where

$$
p_{11} = \frac{b^2 g k + b^2 g + 2 b^2 k + g^2 k + 2 g k^2 + 2 g k}{2 b g k}
$$

$$
p_{12} = -\frac{b^2 g + b^2 k + b^2 + g^2 + g k + g + 2 k^2}{2 b k}
$$

$$
p_{13} = \frac{g + 2 k + g k}{2 g k}
$$

$$
p_{14} = \frac{g + 2}{2 g}
$$

$$
p_{22} = \frac{b^2 g^2 + 2 b^2 g k + b^2 g + b^2 k^2 + b^2 k + g^3 + g^2 k + g^2 + 3 g k^2 + 2 k^3 + 2 k^2}{2 b k^2}
$$

$$
p_{23} = -\frac{g + k + 1}{2 k}
$$

$$
p_{24} = -\frac{1}{2}
$$

$$
p_{33} = \frac{g + 2 k + 2 g k}{2 b g k}
$$

$$
p_{34} = -\frac{g^2 + g - 2 k}{2 b g k}
$$

$$
p_{44} = \frac{b^2 g^2 + b^2 g k + b^2 g + g^3 + g^2 + 2 g k^2 - g k + 2 k^2}{2 b g k^2}
$$

I think it is possible to show to $V\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$ is positive definite and $\dot{V}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$ is negative definite over $0 < |x_{2}| < \pi$.

```
p11 = (b^2*g*k + b^2*g + 2*b^2*k + g^2*k + 2*g*k^2 + 2*g*k)/(2*b*g*k)
p12 = -(b^2*g + b^2*k + b^2 + g^2 + g*k + g + 2*k^2)/(2*b*k)
p13 = (g + 2*k + g*k)/(2*g*k)
p14 = (g + 2)/(2*g)
p22 = (b^2*g^2 + 2*b^2*g*k + b^2*g + b^2*k^2 + b^2*k + g^3 + g^2*k + g^2 + 3*g*k^2 + 2*k^3 + 2*k^2)/(2*b*k^2)
p23 = -(g + k + 1)/(2*k)
p24 = -1/2
p33 = (g + 2*k + 2*g*k)/(2*b*g*k)
p34 = -(g^2 + g - 2*k)/(2*b*g*k)
p44 = (b^2*g^2 + b^2*g*k + b^2*g + g^3 + g^2 + 2*g*k^2 - g*k + 2*k^2)/(2*b*g*k^2)
```